# Goldman's Transformation Puzzle

Tags: geometry

In an old book (*) I found an advert with a puzzle I had never seen before.

[image: Original copy]

Unfortunately the book is very rare and it is hard to make out in the scanned photocopy above. I have redrawn it:

[image: Goldman's transformation puzzle]

It looks a bit like the classic Tangram puzzle, but it consists of three identical trapezoid/trapezium shapes and three triangles of different sizes.

> With these pieces **you have to form a square, and then transform it into a triangle by moving only two pieces**.

*) The book was *The Arithmachinist* by Henry Goldman, from 1898. It was a self-published book promoting the [mechanical calculator](https://youtu.be/_JYz_Q_HEgk) that he invented. A pdf file of the book can be found on [this page](http://djm.cc/dmoews.html). I have not been able to find a patent, and assume that the patent application was rejected.

Comment: Do we have to start with this particular square ?

Comment: @classicalMpk: I didn't think so, but El-Guest's answer shows it can be done with that square too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to do this as follows:

> [image]

Edit: it works! Before picture:

> [image]

And after picture:

> [image]

Please excuse my lack of scissors. The pieces to be moved are therefore

> 5 and 6 as per my diagram.

Comment: Very good! I hadn't found a solution that started with the original square arrangement, only one with a different square, and I then moved two trapezoids. That's why I phrased my question so as to leave the starting square arrangement undetermined.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about using a different square to start but I wasn’t clever enough to find that at first.

Answer (score -2):

[image: Square I have in mind.]

[image: Possible Solution!]

I hope this would be of some help.
The question clearly says we have independence of forming our own square